# separate one file to many files with a certain field

Tags: c#

I have a file txt that contains 6 columns and 6 millions rows. A few lines of the file are as follows:

```
memberId    productId   Date    numberOfHelpfulFeedbacks    numberOfFeedbacks   Rating
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
A1004AX2J2HXGL  B0007RT9LC  May 30, 2005    3   4   5.0
A1004AX2J2HXGL  B00028HBKM  January 17, 2005    9   22  1.0
A1VPPWX7RDEIWC  0140272119  October 12, 1998    1   1   5.0
A100UZ3LRLU135  0345446860  January 9, 2006 1   1   5.0
A100YHBWL4TR4D  0446672211  April 30, 2000  0   1   5.0
A100YHBWL4TR4D  0460872974  April 23, 2001  7   10  5.0
A100TW8FZECWD6  B00009KO14  March 13, 2004  36  39  3.0
A100YHBWL4TR4D  044022425X  December 23, 1999   1   1   2.0
A1VPGZKFSL2Z6J  0671891510  October 31, 1997    1   2   5.0
....
.
.
.
.
```

I want that all lines are in a year, to be kept in a separate file. The lines related to 2000 (2001 and etc) are kept in a separate file.

Comment: what was your own attempt to do it? show some code,

Answer (score 0):

Use `StreamReader` class and read line by line, in each line you can process it and check the year. based on the year write that line to to a new file if there is no file related to given year otherwise you can append to file. for writing perpose you can use `StreamWriter(filename, true)` for append.

Comment: excuse me.I do not know C # code. can you can help me?